# how do I use the key of an object inside the object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to design an interface for postComments, it looks like this:

```
interface PostComments {
    postId:{
        id: string;
        comment: string;
        postId: string;
    }[]
}
```

I want the compiler to give me an error when the postId's are not the same

the progress that I made so far is:

```
interface Comment<T> {
    id: string;
    comment: string;
    postId: T
}

interface PostComments {
    [postId:string]:Comment<PostComments.postId>[];
}
```

but unlucky me, typescript is not happy with the interface that I wrote, how can I throw a compile time exception for this? please let me know if someone have an idea about it.

=========================================================================

i want the comments object to look like:

```
comments = {
    "abc123": [
        {
            id: "xyz098",
            comment: "a sample comment",
            postId: "abc123",
        },
        {
            id: "xyz987",
            comment: "another sample comment",
            postId: "abc123",
        },
    ],
    "bcd123": [
        {
            id: "yxz098",
            comment: "a new sample comment",
            postId: "bcd123",
        },
        {
            id: "yxz987",
            comment: "another new sample comment",
            postId: "bcd123",
        },
    ]
}
```

- notice the keys in comment is same as that of `postId` in every array element of the corrosponding post

Comment: I don’t think typescript can do that, since PostId is always a string and the only way to check if they’re identical is at runtime.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that shows some values you'd like the compiler to accept and some you'd like it to reject?  I'm not 100% sure I understand the data structure.  Still, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYYEQW) meet your needs? If so I'm happy to write up an answer; if not I'd appreciate a set of use cases in the question to code against.